# finding all peaks in phase correlation matrix in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, correlation

I am writing a program in C++ with OpenCv which needs to find the [phase correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation) matrix between two images and find all the peaks present above a response threshold. I did find a function called phaseCorrRes() but it returns only the highest peak using minMaxLoc(). How do I modify this function to retrive all the peaks?

Answer (score 3):

I think you shold use other way to solve your problem, if that function do not useful for you. I recommend you the following steps:

1. Transform you images to the frequency domain with DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform).
2. From the result complex matrix get the phases.
3. Calculate the correlation.
4. Apply some threshold value.

For this steps you need:

1. [`dft()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#dft)
2. [`phase()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=dft#phase)
3. [`matchTemplate()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html#matchtemplate) with `method = CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED`
4. [`threshold()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold) with `type = THRESH_TOZERO`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I am trying to use [phase correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation) for finding if different regions have been shifted by different offsets. The first step you mentioned goes well but the second step does not follow the method as mentioned in the link. I am only a beginner so I don't have much idea. Also matchTemplate requires me to compare two Mat objects and I am not sure if sub Matrix of the output of phase() is to be matched with the complete output . Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to follow the sequence as mentioned in the phaseCorrRes(). we can just add two more steps after carrying FFTShift() which are normalization and threshold. Now if we just change the pixels near and at each peak extracted using minMaxLoc() to 0 (i.e. black) we can iteratively find all the peaks using minMaxLoc(). However, just change the function by creating a copy of the function in the program and not in the original source code.